# Count length of array and return 1 if it only contains one element

Tags: arrays, powershell

```
$cars = "bmw","audi","volvo","vw"
echo $cars.length
```

returns 4, but

```
$cars = "bmw"
```

returns 3 because it counts the characters..

Is there a way I can return 1 if the array only contains one item?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A couple other options:

1. Use the comma operator to create an array:

   ```
   $cars = ,"bmw"
   $cars.GetType().FullName
   # Outputs: System.Object[]
   ```
2. Use array subexpression syntax:

   ```
   $cars = @("bmw")
   $cars.GetType().FullName
   # Outputs: System.Object[]
   ```

If you don't want an object array you can downcast to the type you want e.g. a string array.

```
 [string[]] $cars = ,"bmw"
 [string[]] $cars = @("bmw")
```

Comment: Thank Andy! I see that my script is failing because the value if system.object[]. Is there a way to process the contents as strings?

Comment: @Sune Yea you just down-cast to a string array. I added examples.

Comment: The proposal to use string array didn't work for me. I'm grabbing data from SQL database and it returned "System.Data.DataRow" instead of values. So I had to use the solution with @($array).count below.

Answer (score 28):

Instead of writing `echo $cars.length` write `echo @($cars).length`

Comment: That helped me a lot. An array with 1 element "$packs.Count" didn't returning anything. With several elements it worked well. After changing it to "@($packs).count" it returned 1 for 1 element too. Great thanks! Can you explain this behavior?

Answer (score 8):

declare you array as:

```
$car = array("bmw")
```

**EDIT**

now with powershell syntax:)

```
$car = [array]"bmw"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did not accept it as an answer though, because the syntax is off. Maybe for another language? Thank you anyways:)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something (lots of many-upvotes-members answers here that seem to be looking at this different to I, which would seem implausible that I am correct), but length is not the correct terminology for counting something. Length is usually used to obtain what you are getting, and not what you are wanting.

`$cars.count` should give you what you seem to be looking for.

Comment: Depends on the objects-type with these properties. Say a `file` (or `string`), its `length` refers to its size, whereas its `count` refers to the number of files in question. So they are not identical. But with an `array`, the `length` of an `array` and its `count` are identical. If so inclined, jump into the rabbit hole @ [Length, Count and arrays – Cloud Notes](https://www.cloudnotes.io/length-count-and-arrays/). It is not that deep :)