# how to iterate $TwitterStatuses as an array or as Objects?

Tags: arrays, powershell, loops, .net-core, iteration

How can I iterate each `$TwitterStatuses` element/item/object?

(And, how do I inspect each "status"?)

```
Import-Module PSTwitterAPI


Set-TwitterOAuthSettings -ApiKey $env:ApiKey -ApiSecret $env:ApiSecret -AccessToken $env:AccessToken -AccessTokenSecret $env:AccessTokenSecret

#Get-TwitterUsers_Lookup -screen_name 'mkellerman'

$TwitterStatuses = Get-TwitterStatuses_UserTimeline -screen_name 'mkellerman'
#$TwitterStatuses = [array]Get-TwitterStatuses_UserTimeline -screen_name 'mkellerman'

Foreach ($status in $TwitterStatuses)
{
   Write-Host $status
}
```

I was reading what looked [like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9580310/262852) a sort of "cast" to array usage, but not sure of the distinction from objects here.

see also:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/basics-of-powershell-looping-foreach/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is good already. You don't need to cast to array. 
What you get from `Get-TwitterStatuses_UserTimeline` is already an array of results.

You can check which type is an object by calling the `.GetType()` method on them.

`$TwitterStatuses.GetType()`

[image]

(The `Get-Type` method is available for all objects)

You can inspect the members available using `Get-Member` on the object you want to inspect.

`$TwitterStatuses | Get-Member`

[image]

Then, in your foreach, you need to precise what you actually want to display.

**Example**

```
Foreach ($status in $TwitterStatuses)
{
   Write-Host $status.text
}
```

If only one of the property interest you, you can even get the results directly by accessing the property name . 
The collection will be iterated and results displayed in the console.

`$TwitterStatuses.text`

[image]

**References**

[Get-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-7)

[.GetType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8)